# Trouble connecting to an api with Volley

Tags: android, json, android-studio, curl

I've been stuck with this problem for a while. What I want is to connect to an api whereas curl url is:

curl --header "Authorization: Token 9ea49e1ccb828fd7736d981aa3b027571da9ae86" https://owlbot.info/api/v4/dictionary/owl -s | json_pp

I've been told by my teacher that Volley is the way to go when requesting Curl, so I tried to implement some code that handles connecting with the API, but something is not just right. For test purpose I convert the JSONObject response to string, so it can be set into a textview to se if I can get something out in the emulator, but nothing happens. 
I then tried to use Postman, and see if I whatsoever could get a response from the api by just typing the url and Authroization header, and I can do that.

```java
private void httpRequestWithVolley() {
    String server_url = "https://owlbot.info/api/v4/dictionary/owl";
    final String API_TOKEN = "9ea49e1ccb828fd7736d981aa3b027571da9ae86";

    // Initialize a new RequestQueue instance
    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            server_url,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // Process the JSON
                    try {
                        String json = response.toString();
                        textView.setText(json);

                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("definitions");

                        // Loop through the array elements
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String definition = jsonObject.getString("definition");
                            String image = jsonObject.getString("image_url");
                            int picture = Integer.parseInt(image);

                        }

                        String word = response.getString("word");
                        String pronunciation = response.getString("pronunciation");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    ) {
        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            return super.getBody();
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            // return super.getHeaders();

            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("Authorization", "Token " + API_TOKEN);
            return map;


        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one thing that might give you a problem, is the /Owl in the URL, because that the API, url is ending with the /dictionary, and owl is the word you are searching for, so i think your url should look like this:
"https://owlbot.info/api/v4/dictionary/" and then you can add on the word you want in another method maybe.

I hope this helps.